# Issues with newline while using blat

Tags: windows, email, batch-file, cmd, blat

I have to send a mail via BLAT. We are shifting from Postie to BLAT. The send mail refuses to send the mail via a batch file.

My code goes as follows

```
REM ########### Initialize BLAT SMTP Server and User Name #######################
ECHO.
%V_EMAIL_PATH%\blat.exe -install %V_HOST% "mno@xyz.com"
ECHO.

REM ------------------------ Send Email Notifications ---------------
@ECHO ON
set V_EMAIL_ID="abcd@xyz.com"
set V_SUBJ="Test mail to a group"
set V_MSG="Hello|test mail to prevent failure during delivery while sending automated mails|Thanks|mno"


GOTO Sendemail

:Sendemail


%V_EMAIL_PATH%\blat.exe -body %V_MSG% -to "%V_EMAIL_ID%" -from "mno@xyz.com" -subject "Test Mail"
```

The error being thrown is as follows

`D:\pmserver\pm-work\Utilities\blat.exe -body "Hello test mail to prevent failure during delivery while sending automated mails. Thanks RM Primary" -to "abcd@xyz.com" -from "mno@xyz.com" -subject "Test Mail"

Blat v2.2.2 (build : Feb 26 2004 10:37:13)`

Blat saw and processed these options, and was confused by the last one...

```
Hello|test mail to prevent failure during delivery while sending automated mails.|Thanks|mno
```

Do not understand argument: `Hello|test mail to prevent failure during delivery while sending automated mails|Thanks|mno`

I tried using breakline as well but even that is failing.

reekar V

Comment: try escaping the pipe with the carret ? `^`

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
@echo OFF &SETLOCAL
set "V_EMAIL_ID=abcd@xyz.com"
set "V_SUBJ=Test mail to a group"
set "V_MSG=Hello|test mail to prevent failure during delivery while sending automated mails|Thanks|mno"

%V_EMAIL_PATH%\blat -body "%V_MSG%" -to "%V_EMAIL_ID%" -from "mno@xyz.com" -subject "Test Mail"
```